# Modify color of NSOutlineView in code

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview

I' ve a subclass of NSOutlineView that use View as cells (I use a TextField). The problem is that i Can simply change the color of the row in IB changing the TextFieldCell color but I can' t do that in code. Can anyone help me? thanks!

Comment: By using a view-based collection view, you've forgone the need for Cells.  Modify `-drawRect:` on your cells for custom background colors.

Comment: I use a view-based `NSOutlineView` The problem is that I need to change the font color not the background color. I wan' t to have one color for the item without child and another color for the items child of other item. There' s a way to have 2 separate colors? Thanks

Comment: Set it as a property of the views you've dequeued for the outline view.

Comment: Sorry but I can' t understand your suggestion

Comment: How the heck have you been using view-based outlines without writing a custom view?  View-based `NSOutlineView`'s are ***entirely custom***.  The concept of cells, gone, the concept of pre-defined cells, gone as well.

Comment: As prototype view I use the `NSTextFieldCell class but I understand that the problem is that the group are not used as standard cell but it seems that they are drawed in a different way of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found that the solution is to override the `NSOutlineView` method `- (void)highlightSelectionInClipRect:(NSRect)theClipRect` and draw your custom highlight.